# how to make sub total and grand total blank using DAX in tabular model?

Tags: dax, tabular

```
12 Month Qty:=CALCULATE ( 
     [Qty],
   DATESINPERIOD ( 
       Calendar[Date] , 
       MAX(Calendar[Date]),
       -12, Month
   ) 
)
```

currently i have that formula for my measurement.
However i would like to make all sub totals and grad totals to be blank. Therefore i would need to put ISFILTERED function properly. i wrapped formula with if(ISFILTERED()) and it did not work well. So how can i implement ISFILTERED function correctly? or if I have to use different formula what formula should i use for this situation?

Comment: What didn't work well? What did you expect to see? What did you actually see? Screenshots or sample workbooks are helpful. Model diagrams are useful to understand your structure. What field were you testing with ISFILTERED()?

Comment: adsd:=IF (
    ISFILTERED ([Local])
        && NOT ( ISFILTERED ( [Local] ) ),
    CALCULATE (
        [Local],
        DATESINPERIOD (
            Calendar[Date],
            MAX ( Calendar[Date] ),
            -12,
            MONTH
        )
    )
)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.it gives me error column 'local' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression, Because local is a measure. Do you have any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments on the original question:

ISFILTERED() has to take a column as its argument, not a measure. ISFILTERED() will tell you if a filter has been applied (via a pivot table row, column, filter, or slicer) to a specific column in your model. Thus you can use it to suppress evaluation of a measure at certain levels of the hierarchy.

Say you have a measure that you want to display as a BLANK when at the subcategory level of a hierarchy that goes Category>SubCategory>Item:

```
IF(
    ISFILTERED(<table>[SubCategory])
    ,BLANK()
    ,[Measure]
)
```

This would return a blank anywhere that [SubCategory] column has a filter applied.

Edit for comment:

Whichever level of the hierarchy you want to blank is the column to reference in ISFILTERED().

I'll typically use this pattern with a date hierarchy to display different levels of aggregation, and I tend to prefer HASONEVALUE() as my test. I'll apply a series of these tests in a SWITCH() function. SWITCH() is merely syntactic sugar for nested IF()s - you can look it up if you need a reference.

Thus:

```
MyConditionalMeasure:=
SWITCH( TRUE()
    ,HASONEVALUE(DimDate[Date] 
        // This means we're at the date level of the hierarchy
    ,[BaseMeasure] // The measure to evaluate at that first level
    ,HASONEVALUE(DimDate[Month]) 
        // This is true for a month or a date only, but we've
        // already captured the date possibility above
    ,[Month-appropriate Aggregation of BaseMeasure]
    ,HASONEVALUE(DimDate[Year])
        // Again, true for a single date or a single month, but
        // we've already covered those, so the year level is all
        // that's left
    ,[Year-appropriate Aggregation of BaseMeasure]
    ,BLANK() // The last argument is taken as a final ELSE
        // condition, capturing anything we didn't cover above,
        // which would include the grand total - this will blank the
        // grand total, or e.g. DimDate[Decade] since that is a
        // coarser granularity than we covered with our tests above
```

Comment: i am using this for hierarchy, so do i put parent column there? and what if i want to make blank on grand total rows too?

Comment: Asdasdasdaasd :=
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    HASONEVALUE ( [level04] ), CALCULATE (
        [Local],
        DATESINPERIOD (
            Calendar[Date],
            MAX ( Calendar[ Date] ),
            -12,
            MONTH
        ),
        HASONEVALUE ( [level03] ),
        CALCULATE (
            [Local],
            DATESINPERIOD (
                Calendar[Date],
                MAX ( Calendar[Date] ),
                -12,
                MONTH
            ),
            HASONEVALUE ([level02] ),
            BLANK ()
        )
    )
)

Comment: Thank you for your support! I tried like that but it gives me error "The True/False expression does not specify a column." How can I add True/False expression?

Comment: You're not closing your CALCULATE()s at the appropriate point. Everything after the first DATESINPERIOD() is included in the first CALCULATE()

Comment: thank you! after closing my calculate correctly it works!